# Parse Cloud Background Job does not stop execution with call of .success()

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, parse-platform, jobs

I was assuming that calling `status.success()` terminates background job. However, when I run it, I still see the second log message:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("Tester", function (request, status) {
    console.log("Starting our Test ...");
    status.success("done!");

    // I still see this!
    console.log("We don't get here!"); 
});
```

Here are the logs:

```
I2014-05-07T09:41:51.504Z]v344 Ran job Tester with:
  Input: {}
  Result: done!
I2014-05-07T09:41:51.520Z]Starting our Test ...
I2014-05-07T09:41:51.520Z]We don't get here!
```

If this is not the way, how else I can terminate the job?

---

UPDATE. Found a quote that lead me to think it does terminate the job. (Apparently it doesn't):

https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-upsert

> Make sure you're not calling response.success() outside of >the find() callback, which would terminate your Cloud Code >prematurely.
>
> - Héctor Ramos  about 1 year ago

Comment: If you provide some info on the use case where you need to terminate the job, it will be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Handsomeguy I want to terminate the job e.g. when things go crazy like an outside server failure. Then instead of keeping trying I'd rather wait. Of course, I can artificially do nothing till the timeout but I've thought terminating might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen other people wondering the same thing, but it doesn't seem to be a way. All I can think of is to have some kind of check for the availability of external services, and maybe that the format of the response you get is correct, and then if these are not OK, then call status.error() and not have code to execute after that. If something happens while your job is progressing, I don't believe there is any way to abort the job before it times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `status.success()` terminates the job (maybe `status.error()` does). In any example I have seen, status.success() is only used to indicate that the job has finished successfully. If `status.success()` is not called, the job will time out after 15 minutes.

You need to use other functionality to abort code progress.

From the guide (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs-writing):

> "You should add the status.success() statement when the code completes
>   successfully."

Comment: I was dealing with a similar issue for a few hours today, and ended up throwing an exception - `throw "Your message";`. This causes all code, both on thread and async, to terminate and travel to the end of the Cloud function to see if something catches it. If nothing catches it, no problem, because it would still log your message (which can be a positive one) to console

Comment: Just found out about a more elegant solution to return a `Parse.Promise.error("Your message");` instead of throwing an exception which stops execution of all code and looks for the error callback at the end of the chain of promises